# Check if a varchar is a number (T-SQL)

Tags: t-sql, numerical-methods

Is there an easy way to figure out if a varchar is a number?

Examples:

> abc123 --> no number
>
> 123 --> yes, its a number

Comment: `isnumeric` but it [has a lot of quirks](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/302466/isnumeric-returns-true-for-and)

Comment: I added a link above to a Microsoft Connect item with both some examples and the MS explanation. What number formats do you need to match? For example would you need to match something like `1e23`?

Comment: In case of IsNumeric quirks, how about going for TRY_CAST(ReqCol As INT) IS NOT NULL?

Comment: pls accept damien's answer

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[ISNUMERIC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx) will do

Check the NOTES section too in the article.

Comment: @Grady - I think Damien's answer below is a better one as pointed out, IsNumeric does have some restrictions. Are you sure, you dont encounter any such restrictions?

Comment: scroll down to notice the next answer.

Comment: "select isnumeric('138D47')" returns 1

Comment: -1 There are many things which isNumeric is true for, but which will exception if cast to INT or Float -- see https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/02/fifteen-things-hate-isnumeric for some examples - which shows the following 15 strings are all "IsNumeric"=1 '$' ,'£' ,',' ,'.' ,'0e+99' ,'2e2' ,'12D4' ,',1,1,1,1,1,1,1' ,'-' ,'+' ,CHAR(9) ,CHAR(10) ,CHAR(11) ,CHAR(12) ,CHAR(13)

Comment: @Nuzzolilo Because it seems to be numeric if it is an hexadeciaml thing, and d is part of hexa thing

Comment: I am still getting error on below query

 Declare @testVal as varchar(50)='ok'
select CASE WHEN IsNUMERIC(@testVal)=1 THEN Cast(@testVal as numeric) ELSE 'n' End

Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 161):

ISNUMERIC will not do - it tells you that the string can be converted to *any* of the numeric types, which is almost always a pointless piece of information to know. For example, all of the following are numeric, according to ISNUMERIC:

> £, $, 0d0

If you want to check for digits and only digits, a negative LIKE expression is what you want:

```
not Value like '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: ISNUMERIC also considers a "-" to be numeric.

Comment: This is a great method if you only want positive integers, but I've added some examples below if you need to allow other kinds of numeric types too if you're using SQL 2012+.

Comment: Definitely, better answer than ISNUMERIC! This should be the marked as correct answer.

Comment: This and other similar answers will say the first example in the original question IS a number, because one of it's characters is a number. What about if you want to know that ALL characters are numbers.

Comment: @RosieC - no, the example in my code, `not Value like '%[^0-9]%'`, is, exactly, that all characters are digits. It's a double-negative. It asserts that no character in `Value` is outside of the range `0-9`.

Comment: @RosieC - or, to put it another way - `Value like '%[0-9]%'` would be "the string contains at least one digit character". `Value like '%[^0-9]%'` would be "the string contains at least one non-digit character". But, again, my test is `not Value like '%[^0-9]%'` which negates the previous test and is "the string contains no non-digit characters"

Answer (score 34):

You can check like this:

```
declare @vchar varchar(50)
set @vchar ='34343';
select case when @vchar not like '%[^0-9]%' then 'Number' else 'Not a Number' end
```

Answer (score 25):

Using SQL Server 2012+, you can use the TRY_* functions if you have specific needs.  For example,

```
-- will fail for decimal values, but allow negative values
TRY_CAST(@value AS INT) IS NOT NULL 

-- will fail for non-positive integers; can be used with other examples below as well, or reversed if only negative desired
TRY_CAST(@value AS INT) > 0

-- will fail if a $ is used, but allow decimals to the specified precision
TRY_CAST(@value AS DECIMAL(10,2)) IS NOT NULL 

-- will allow valid currency
TRY_CAST(@value AS MONEY) IS NOT NULL  

-- will allow scientific notation to be used like 1.7E+3
TRY_CAST(@value AS FLOAT) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This is the best solution. The solutions using %[^0-9.]% seem to return say it's a number when it contains a number even if there are also characters in the string. This TRY_CAST works for me.

Comment: Just keep in mind it requires SQL Server 2012+ - won't work on 2008R2 or lower, and won't work in other RDBMS

Answer (score 9):

I ran into the need to allow decimal values, so I used `not Value like '%[^0-9.]%'`

Comment: This is not good. It would have matched with just `.`, `2.2.2...1....0`, `2.1.2` and so on. You would need a second condition to also exclude ones with more than one decimal point, and those where the decimal is not between two numbers.

Answer (score 3):

[Wade73's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-t-sql/27234691#27234691) for decimals doesn't quite work. I've modified it to allow only a single decimal point.

```
declare @MyTable table(MyVar nvarchar(10));
insert into @MyTable (MyVar)
values
    (N'1234')
    , (N'000005')
    , (N'1,000')
    , (N'293.8457')
    , (N'x')
    , (N'+')
    , (N'293.8457.')
    , (N'......');

-- This shows that Wade73's answer allows some non-numeric values to slip through.
select * from (
    select
        MyVar
        , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber
    from
        @MyTable
) t order by IsNumber;

-- Notice the addition of "and MyVar not like N'%.%.%'".
select * from (
    select
        MyVar
        , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' and MyVar not like N'%.%.%' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber
    from
        @MyTable
) t
order by IsNumber;
```

Comment: And I had to add  <> '.' Thankfully none of my data has a '-' in the wrong place

Answer (score 2):

[Damien_The_Unbeliever noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-t-sql/4603388#4603388) that his was only good for digits

[Wade73 added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-t-sql/27234691#27234691) a bit to handle decimal points

[neizan made](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35463487/) an additional tweak as [did notwhereuareat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-t-sql/35463487#35463487).

Unfortunately, none appear to handle negative values and they appear to have issues with a comma in the value...

Here's my tweak to pick up negative values and those with commas

```
declare @MyTable table(MyVar nvarchar(10));
insert into @MyTable (MyVar) 
values 
(N'1234')
, (N'000005')
, (N'1,000')
, (N'293.8457')
, (N'x')
, (N'+')
, (N'293.8457.')
, (N'......')
, (N'.')
, (N'-375.4')
, (N'-00003')
, (N'-2,000')
, (N'3-3')
, (N'3000-')
;

-- This shows that Neizan's answer allows "." to slip through.
select * from (
select 
    MyVar
    , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber 
from 
    @MyTable
) t order by IsNumber;

-- Notice the addition of "and MyVar not like '.'".
select * from (
select 
    MyVar
    , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' and MyVar not like N'%.%.%' and MyVar not like '.' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber 
from 
    @MyTable
) t 
order by IsNumber;

--Trying to tweak for negative values and the comma
--Modified when comparison
select * from (
select 
    MyVar
    , case 
        when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.,-]%' and MyVar not like '.' and isnumeric(MyVar) = 1 then 1
        else 0 
    end as IsNumber 
from 
    @MyTable
) t 
order by IsNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @A nvarchar(100) = '12'
IF(ISNUMERIC(@A) = 1)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'YES NUMERIC'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

[Neizan's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-t-sql/33701940#33701940) lets values of just a "." through. At the risk of getting too pedantic, I added one more `AND` clause.

```
declare @MyTable table(MyVar nvarchar(10));
insert into @MyTable (MyVar) 
values 
    (N'1234')
    , (N'000005')
    , (N'1,000')
    , (N'293.8457')
    , (N'x')
    , (N'+')
    , (N'293.8457.')
    , (N'......')
    , (N'.')
    ;

-- This shows that Neizan's answer allows "." to slip through.
select * from (
    select 
        MyVar
        , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber 
    from 
        @MyTable
) t order by IsNumber;

-- Notice the addition of "and MyVar not like '.'".
select * from (
    select 
        MyVar
        , case when MyVar not like N'%[^0-9.]%' and MyVar not like N'%.%.%' and MyVar not like '.' then 1 else 0 end as IsNumber 
    from 
        @MyTable
) t 
order by IsNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to exclude carriage returns from your data!

As in:

```
SELECT 
  Myotherval
  , CASE WHEN TRIM(REPLACE([MyVal], char(13) + char(10), '')) not like '%[^0-9]%' and RTRIM(REPLACE([MyVal], char(13) + char(10), '')) not like '.' and isnumeric(REPLACE([MyVal], char(13) + char(10), '')) = 1 THEN 'my number: ' +  [MyVal]
             ELSE ISNULL(Cast([MyVal] AS VARCHAR(8000)), '')
        END AS 'MyVal'
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add a constraint on a field:

Positive integer with fixed length

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.BankBranchType  
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_TransitNumberMustBe5Digits 
CHECK (TransitNumber NOT like '%[^0-9]%'  
       AND LEN(TransitNumber) = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the Number, Currency, and Amount, use the below SQL fragment.

```
@value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.,]%'
```

For a quick win, refer to the below example:

**Function example:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCheckValueIsNumber](
    @value NVARCHAR(255)=NULL
)RETURNS INT  AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @ReturnValue INT=0
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * WHERE @value NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.,]%') SELECT @ReturnValue=1
RETURN @ReturnValue;
```

**Execution result**

```
SELECT [dbo].[fnCheckValueIsNumber]('12345')
RESULT = 1

SELECT [dbo].[fnCheckValueIsNumber]('10020.25')
RESULT = 1

SELECT [dbo].[fnCheckValueIsNumber]('10,020.25')
RESULT = 1

SELECT [dbo].[fnCheckValueIsNumber]('12,345ABCD')
RESULT = 0
```