# T-SQL Group By; Contains or IfAny

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there any kind of built-in aggregate, within T-SQL,  like Contains or IfAny or whatever?  Something where any in the group equals a value?
Similar to `Max(xyz)=value` except not limited to max.

```sql
select custID, 
    case when Min(ProductGroup)= "A"
        then 'Have Ordered Group A'
        else 'Have not Ordered Group A'
    end hasOrdered
from orders
inner join products on ordPoductId = productID
group by custID
```

This works for a single value comparison, if it is min/max, but instead I want something like:

```sql
select custID, 
    case when Min(ProductGroup)= "A"
        then 'Have Ordered Group A'
        else 'Have not Ordered Group A'
    end hasOrdered
from orders
inner join products on ordPoductId = productID
group by custID
```

I could use `Min(ProductGroup)="A"` if the value I'm concerned about is a min/max or change the from-clause to `(case when 'G' then 0 else 1 end)` to create a fake maximum.

Currently I am only concerned with a single value, but I would like something more intuitive and flexible if possible.
Any ideas?

Comment: Another way to put it could be AnyLike(columns, 'RegularExpression').  That doesn't exist, so I still don't know a solution however.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which is the least expensive aggregate function in the absence of ANY()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6060241/which-is-the-least-expensive-aggregate-function-in-the-absence-of-any)

Answer (score 22):

Your examples at the end are close to what I'd normally do. Something like:

```
CASE MAX(CASE WHEN ProductGroup = 'G' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
   WHEN 1 THEN 'Have Ordered'
   ELSE 'Haven''t ordered'
END
```

Where the inner `CASE` expression will obviously be evaluated against each row, whereas the outer `CASE` expression determines whether the inner expression ever succeeded.

Comment: @wilsjd - I never nag people for accepts - if they stick around for a while and participate, they'll tend to get around to it eventually. If they don't stick around, nagging them is probably another reason for them to leave. And `peter` hasn't been seen for 2+ years, so I doubt this will ever be accepted.

Comment: @wilsjd - my favourite example is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4603388/15498) - if `grady` ever turns up and changes their accepted answer, then all of a sudden the juxtaposition is ruined, and I'd hate that.