# Condition in where clause to return values that starts with letters?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to set a condition in the where clause to return the values that contains letters.
Here is an example of my data: one is pure numeric 123456789 and one is mixed AB1234567

I only want to return the mixed letter/numeric values.

Thanks

Edit: Both methods in the answers below work fine!
You guys are awesome!

I found an easier way by using `where col>'A'`
Tested the result against the answered scripts and they returned the same.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a varchar is a number (TSQL)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603292/check-if-a-varchar-is-a-number-tsql)

Comment: @squiguy The question that you have mentioned pertains to TSQL and not Oracle SQL.

Comment: @JosephB I didn't know if it was exactly similar, but the idea is the same.

Comment: @squiguy Agreed. But, the accepted answer in the other question will not work for Oracle. So, it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
where LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE(YourField, ' +-.0123456789', ' '))) is not null
```

sourced from: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/questions/isnumeric.php

Tested with data containing
MX01386
7493559

is not null returned MX record is null returned numeric record.

What this does in essence is replace each value with a space then trims out that space if the resulting value is null, then it must be numeric.  if it is not null, then it contains characters outside this list ' +-.0123456789'

Comment: Thanks it works. Actually both of your methods works! But I will go with your method because I need to implement the script into an old legacy system that might not take REGEXP_LIKE.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(column, '[A-Za-z0-9]') and REGEXP_LIKE(column,'[^0-9]')`

The query selects alpha numeric records and filter the numeric one this is done using negate `^`

[Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a5cd2/83)

Comment: If I add another condition 'and column='123456789' behind your query, it will still return the numeric value. I need the query to completely omit the pure numeric records.

Comment: Column containing `MX01386` and `7493559` returned both records.

Comment: add the ' around the 2nd set of []'s and this works too!