# SQL query involving count, group by and substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, group-by

[image]

I would like to group rows of this table according to dates which form the start of `SessionID` and for each day, I would like to count how many rows there are for each set of `ReqPhone` values. Each set of `ReqPhone` values will be defined by the first four digits of `ReqPhone`. In other words, I would like to know how many rows there are for `ReqPhone` starting with `0925`, `0927` and `0940`, how many rows there are for `ReqPhone` starting with `0979`, `0969` and `0955`, etc etc.

I have been trying all kinds of `group by` and `count` but still haven't arrived at the right query.

Can anybody enlighten me?

Update:

In my country, the government assigns telecoms phone numbers starting with certain digits. Therefore, if you know the starting digits, you know which telecom someone is using. I am trying to count how many messages are sent each day using each telecoms.

Comment: Please update your question letting us know the real problem you are trying to solve, thanks.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for solving the problem on my behalf. I had expected more of a guidance than an answer. Thanks a lot for going a mile further to help me. I have updated my question.

Comment: There are several options here.  I could query my answer and use conditional aggregation to obtain counts for the various telecoms based on the signature of the first four digits.  Or, the original query could be rewritten using more complex logic to directly group according to telecom.

Comment: The second option will probably look like this: SELECT (CASE SUBSTRING(ReqPhone, 1, 4) WHEN '0951' THEN 'MPT' WHEN '0941' THEN 'MPT'​ 
WHEN '0931' THEN 'MPT' WHEN '0979' THEN 'Telenor'​​ WHEN '0977' THEN 'Telenor'​​​ END),
       DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID)) AS dayCreated,
       COUNT(*) AS tally
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY 
(CASE SUBSTRING(ReqPhone, 1, 4) WHEN '0951' THEN 'MPT' WHEN '0941' THEN 'MPT'​ 
WHEN '0931' THEN 'MPT' WHEN '0979' THEN 'Telenor'​​ WHEN '0977' THEN 'Telenor'​​​ END)​,
         DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID))

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ReqPhone, 1, 4),
       DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID)) AS dayCreated,
       COUNT(*) AS tally
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ReqPhone, 1, 4),
         DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim but I also want to group the phone numbers according to their carriers. Can this be done?

Comment: I don't see anywhere information about the carriers.  Can you include this information in your question?

Comment: It's like if the number starts with 0945, 0947 or 0949 etc.

Comment: My query is _already_ grouping by the first four digits on the `SessionID` column.  If you need to do additional grouping on top of this, let me know what the logic is and update your question.

Comment: I think I need to create sub queries. My group by will be like what they are doing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815461/group-by-multiple-values-in-same-column)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT LEFT(ReqPhone, 4),
       DATEADD(DAY,0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID)) AS dayCreated,
       COUNT(*) AS tally
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LEFT(ReqPhone,4),
         DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, SessionID))
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to calculate the count of rows group by the `ReqPhone` type. This query is working successfully in Oracle DB.

```
SELECT COUNT(SESSIONID), REQP
FROM (SELECT SESSIONID,SUBSTR(REQPHONE,1,4) AS REQP FROM SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME)
GROUP BY REQP
```

Note: Please use the column which is unique in the `COUNT` expression.